# Important Inequality

Tags: real-analysis

Good morning, I need your help.
Let $(Q_j)_j $ be a partition of $\mathbb{R}^n $ into equal sized cubes ordered so that $j>i $ if
$dist(x,Q_j)>dist(x,Q_i)\;\forall x\in Q_0$.
I want to show that he exist  $c>0$ such that
$$\log(e+dist(x,Q_j))\geq c\log(e+j).$$
Hint the author just this inequality it is true, since there are $(2j)^n$ cubes at distance less than $j sidelength(Q_0) $ from $x $.

But l didn't see why ?

Thanks foward for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. For example if $n=1$, and $Q_0=[0,1)$. What could possibly be $Q_1$?

Comment: If $Q_0=[0,1) $ then $Q_1=[1,2) $.

Comment: But for $0\in Q_0$, and $Q_j$ the cube that contains $0.1$, it holds that $dist(0,Q_j) < dist(0,Q_1)$, even though $j>1$.

Comment: I don't think, because $Q_0=[0,0.1) ,\,Q_1=[0.1,0.2)$ and $Q_2=[0.2,0.3) $

Comment: Maybe you meant that $i>j$ implies $d(Q_0,Q_i) \geq d(Q_0,Q_j)$ where the distance between the sets is the infimum of distances between two points (one in each set respectively)?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the cube that contains $-0.1$.

Comment: Let $x=0$. The relation $d(x,Q_j)>d(x,Q_i )\implies j>i $  is an order relation defined on these cube. $Q_0=[0,0.1), Q_1=[-0.1,0) or [0.1,0.2) $ then $d(0,Q_1)<d(0,Q_2) $